# galleria - run a JavaScript function everytime picture is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, galleria

I am trying to find in the Galleria JavaScript file a place where I tell it to run a JavaScript function every time the current picture is changed (prev, next, or clicking on a thumbnail)

Does anyone with experience with galleria have any ideas?
http://galleria.io/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you set up your Gallery bind to the image function and you will receive the event every time the image changes. I use it to load text into another area of my page like so.

Galleria.ready(function() {
                this.bind("image", function(e) {
                    $("#text_div").text(arrayOfText[e.index]); 
                });
            });

To make sure you have things setup correctly use it like this,

Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/kscreates/galleria.classic.js');
Galleria.configure();
Galleria.ready(function() {
                this.bind("image", function(e) {
                    console.log(e.index); 
                });
            });
Galleria.run('#galleria');

and have a look in your Safari console and you will see the index of the currently displayed image.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response. 
I'm a little confused, I think because I am so new to javascript. 
`Galleria.ready(function() { this.bind("image", functionToRun() });`
so if i just did that, would functionToRun get called eachtime the picture changes?
Thanks

Comment: Yes. It is a feature of the Galleria library, they provide access to this callback. If you try the three lines of code above you can see that every time the picture changes the index of the image will be written to the console.

Comment: No problem let me know how you get on and if you have trouble I can send you a little demo file.